# Life cycle methods in java

Tags: java

How to create a class with some methods that are executing in some order(i.e. Life cycle methods of a class) when a class inheriting this class and override these life cycle methods?

**For Example:**

1. In Servlet first init() is called then service() and at last destroy() is called automatically when a servlet object is created.
2. Activities in android have lifecycle methods onCreate() ,onStart(), onResume() etc which are automatically called when object of an activity come into existence

Comment: You create the class and define the methods. Where's the problem?

Comment: when a class inheriting my class(which has lifecycle methods) then the methods which are overridden by a new class are executing in some order

Comment: Have a look at template method pattern . It lets one redefine certain steps of an algorithm without changing the algorithm's structure http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: This is a under-voted question. It requires deeper understanding of framework and application container. Things gets complicated when you into language compilers.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of these methods is mandated by the framework/container referencing your class. I'd normally expect that your framework would require clients to implement a particular interface (containing `start()`, `stop()` etc.) and the framework *itself* will determine the state machine and subsequent behavior.

Answer (score 1):

**LIFE CYCLE METHODS OF JAVA**

Since applets are running in the browser, the class Applet contains the life cycle methods.
Life cycle methods are also called as loop back methods.

**In java.applet.Applet we have four life cycle methods. They are**

```
public void init (),
public void start (),
public void stop () 
public void destroy ().
```

**1. Public void init ():**

```
This is the method which is called by the browser only one time after loading the applet.
In this method we write some block of statements which will perform one time operations, such as, obtaining the resources like opening the files, obtaining the database connection, initializing the parameters, etc.
```

**2. Public void start ():**

```
  After calling the init method, the next method which is from second request to sub-sequent requests the start method only will be called i.e., short method will be called each and every time.
In this method we write the block of statement which provides business logic.
```

**3. Public void stop ():**

```
  This id the method which is called by the browser when we minimize the window. 
In this method we write the block of statements which will temporarily releases the resources which are obtained in init method.
```

**4. Public void destroy ():**

```
This is the method which will be called by the browser when we close the window button or when we terminate the applet application.
In this method we write same block of statements which will releases the resources permanently which are obtained in init method.
```

Another method which is not a life cycle method is public void paint (). This is the method which
will be called by the browser after completion of start method. This method is used for displaying
the data on to the browser. Paint method is internally calling the method called drawString whose
prototype is given below.
java.awt.Graphics
(Graphics => public void drawString (String, int row position, int column position))
An object of Graphics class will be created automatically after loading the applet into the
browser.

Comment: This is very specific to applets

Comment: This is a under-voted question. It requires deeper understanding of framework and application container. Things gets complicated when you into language compilers.

Answer (score 1):

You need **application container** (the simplest explanation is that it is some class, which would execute specified methods of your classes in specified order). But you need to understand concept of application container deeper. I'd suggest you to read about [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework)

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, your requirement can be met using the template method approach:

```
public class Template {
  public void templateMethod() {
    detail1();
    detail2();
  }
  protected void detail1() {}
  protected void detail2() {}
```

}

And then you subclass the Template class.